Is there a link between the Ezekiel 47 river and John's Living Water?

John 7:37-38 NIV
[37] On the last and greatest day of the festival, Jesus stood and said in a loud voice, “Let anyone who is thirsty come to me and drink. [38] Whoever believes in me, as Scripture has said, rivers of living water will flow from within them.”


John 4:13-14 NIV
[13] Jesus answered, “Everyone who drinks this water will be thirsty again, [14] but whoever drinks the water I give them will never thirst. Indeed, the water I give them will become in them a spring of water welling up to eternal life.”


Ezekiel 47:1-12 NIV
[1] The man brought me back to the entrance to the temple, and I saw water coming out from under the threshold of the temple toward the east (for the temple faced east). The water was coming down from under the south side of the temple, south of the altar. [2] He then brought me out through the north gate and led me around the outside to the outer gate facing east, and the water was trickling from the south side. [3] As the man went eastward with a measuring line in his hand, he measured off a thousand cubits and then led me through water that was ankle-deep. [4] He measured off another thousand cubits and led me through water that was knee-deep. He measured off another thousand and led me through water that was up to the waist. [5] He measured off another thousand, but now it was a river that I could not cross, because the water had risen and was deep enough to swim in---a river that no one could cross. [6] He asked me, “Son of man, do you see this?” Then he led me back to the bank of the river. [7] When I arrived there, I saw a great number of trees on each side of the river. [8] He said to me, “This water flows toward the eastern region and goes down into the Arabah, where it enters the Dead Sea. When it empties into the sea, the salty water there becomes fresh. [9] Swarms of living creatures will live wherever the river flows. There will be large numbers of fish, because this water flows there and makes the salt water fresh; so where the river flows everything will live. [10] Fishermen will stand along the shore; from En Gedi to En Eglaim there will be places for spreading nets. The fish will be of many kinds---like the fish of the Mediterranean Sea. [11] But the swamps and marshes will not become fresh; they will be left for salt. [12] Fruit trees of all kinds will grow on both banks of the river. Their leaves will not wither, nor will their fruit fail. Every month they will bear fruit, because the water from the sanctuary flows to them. Their fruit will serve for food and their leaves for healing …

Do these references to 'rivers of living water' in John 4 and John 7 link with Ezekiel 47?

The river of life is alluded to in Rev 22.

This might still be better as two questions, but I've attempted to refine it somewhat. Feel free to ask about the Tabernacles link as a separate question, it might be tidier if the answers to your two points of inquiry are more involved or unrelated to each other.

FWIW regarding a seed for thoughts on "living water", the Hebrew expression מַ֥יִם חַיִּֽים, given as "running water" in Leviticus 14:5 (KJV), and other places, iliterally means "living water".

The Living WaterMany commentators see the connection of Ezekiel's water with the outpouring of the Holy Spirit! Notice that the water of Ezekiel begins to flow out from the Temple. From there it continues on down past the Kidron Valley to the edge of the Dead Sea (EnGedi). And as it picks up depth in its flow it becomes supernatural in refreshing and healing power.
In the same way. Jesus prophesied that the Holy Spirit would "flow out from the Father" (See Acts 1, John 15-17)) and infill the disciples...which occurred on the Day of Pentecost (Acts 2).

Whoever believes in Me, as scripture has said, rivers of living water will flow from within them. By this He meant the Spirit, whom those who believed in Him were later to receive.Up to that time the Spirit had not been given, since Jesus had not been glorified. (John 7:38-39)

But notice that the disciples were in the Temple daily during the time they were waiting for this infilling. (Luke's Gospel's last verses). It was there that the Holy Spirit water began to flow on the Day of Pentecost, as the disciples were gathered together in worship.
And, as the subsequent history of the Church in Acts demonstrated, the Charismatic-empowered Church began to spread the Gospel throughout the world, increasing its flow of influence as well as size, until they turned the world upside down. Healings---mentioned in Ezekiel---were manifest everywhere they went in the power of the Holy Spirit!
[NOTE: Some assume that the disciples were in "the upper room", where they had previously met to appoint a new Apostle. But the telling of the Pentecostal experience emphasized the presence of Jewish festival pilgrims from all over the Roman Empire. They most likely were in the Temple area complex (10 acres), witnessing the event of the Out-pouring on the Apostles who were in one of the Temple's many meeting halls.]
Continuing And the Holy Spirit water continues to flow in greater and greater areas ministering healing to the nations! Living Water continues to sustain the Church in its mission of spreading the refreshing, life-giving Gospel of Christ.
[NOTE: The Well of Jacob, and the Pool of Siloam---although used to describe living water by Jesus---could not be said to flow. So the metaphor of a river flowing out from the Temple would best be interpreted here as the outpouring of the Holy Spirit from the Temple where the disciples were congregated in worship.]

agree with emphasis that the river of life becomes life when we reach out to others with the gospel message. Find it interesting it was only ankle deep in the sanctuary ( church), whereas the river grew in size and power with distance from the sanctuary i.e. the streets and on mission where those who havent heard the gospel are!

Not necessarily. New Testament references to the "living water" that Jesus brought usually refer to water from the Rock in the wilderness rather than water from the river described in Ezekiel's vision.
1 Cor. 10

I do not want you to be unaware, brothers and sisters, that our
fathers were all under the cloud and they all passed through the sea;
2 and they all were baptized into Moses in the cloud and in the sea; 3
and they all ate the same spiritual food, 4 and all drank the same
spiritual drink, for they were drinking from a spiritual rock which
followed them; and the rock was Christ.

Both Paul and Jesus speak metaphorically of "living water" - the water of baptism which is also consumed as a drink. In that sense Ezekiel's water could be the same, since one need not be baptized in any particular stream. We should also be aware that Jesus spoke of "living water" in relation to the water of Jacob's well (John 4:6) and probably the Pool of Siloam.
